# Extract powers of exponential into a list

Tags: pattern-matching

I have a very complicated, long (thousands of terms) expression that boils down to a form of

```
expr = a1 Exp[b1] + a2 Exp[b2] + a3 Exp[b3]
```

Note that all a and b are huge symbolic expressions but the expression is expanded that way.

Now I would like to get a list with b1, b2, b3.
All I can do is

```
Collect[expr, E^_]
```

but that does not give me a list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Cases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html):

```
Cases[expr, Exp[p_] :> p, All]
```

> {b1, b2, b3}

Alternatively, you can use [`Exponent`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Exponent.html) after changing the head of `expr` to `List`:

```
Exponent[List @@ expr, E]
```

> {b1, b2, b3}